# ASP.NET - Streaming vs Downloading - forward requests

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, stream

We are abstracting the filestore for our ASP.NET application, the file can be served from file system or S3 or any other filestore. Now for the filestore other than filesystem we need to send a request to get the file and serve it. Used two approaches:

- Download the file completely and serve it along with Content-Length header

  ```
                            or
  ```
- Pass the stream to the response in this case **Transfer-Encoding: chunked** is sent along with the request

Our data includes thousands of js/css/images/mp3 files. Each JS/CSS/image file is usually in KB's, audio files may be in MB's

Should we go with streaming or downloading approach? Don't want to do a mix to avoid complexity.

What is the file size boundary after which one should use streaming instead of downloading?

Comment: Why not directly download from S3 to client? This way you have double the traffic. One from S3 to your Server and one from your Server to your Client. Or is it not an option?

Comment: It is not an option as our server is akamized, serving it from s3 defeats the purpose